# Determine position of values in dictionary, Python

Tags: python, dictionary

There is a dictionary that may include keys starting from 0 and values: a, b, c, d, e. Each time the values may be assigned to different keys keys. Size of the dictionary may change as well.

I am interested in two values. Let's call them b and d.
Is there any algorithm that determine situations when b appears earlier than d (i.e. b's key is smaller than d's) and when d appears earlier than b (i.e. d's key is is smaller than b's)?

Comment: Alright. Maybe I was wrong trying to use dictionary and should have used some other technique. I am writing add-on for some software. Using its classes, I get a few objects that string property (name) and integer proerty (index). So, what i need to do is to determine which object goes first to continue program.

Answer (score 5):

A dictionary has no order. So your wording "b's key is smaller than d's" is the right one.

Now, it looks like you could swap keys and values...

Comment: My drictionary will be ordered, starting from 0, in ascending order

Comment: @Maks: Are you sure a list wouldn't do the job better?

Comment: How could i use a list in this case?

Comment: @Maks: `mylist = ["a","b","c","d","e"]`, then `mylist.index("d")` will give you the (first) position of "d".

Answer (score 1):

If the values are hashable then you could generate a reverse dictionary and check the values. Otherwise, you'll need to brute-force it.

```
def dictfind(din, tsent, fsent):
  for k in sorted(din.iterkeys()):
    if din[k] == tsent:
      return True
    if din[k] == fsent:
      return False
  else:
    raise ValueError('No match found')

D = {0:'a', 1:'b', 2:'c', 3:'d', 4:'e'}

print dictfind(D, 'b', 'd')
```

Comment: You should be able to brute force it in O(n), but this algorithm is O(n logn) because of the sort

Comment: Bear in mind that the O(n) method requires touching every element whereas this one stops as soon as it sees the first one.

Comment: The sort also touches every element albeit very quickly compared to a python loop.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are unordered sets of key-value pairs. `dict.keys()` need not produce the same output always. Can't you do what you want with lists?

Answer (score 0):

First create your dictionary

```
>>> import random
>>> keys = range(5)
>>> random.shuffle(keys)
>>> d=dict(zip(keys, "abcde"))
>>> d
{0: 'd', 1: 'c', 2: 'e', 3: 'b', 4: 'a'}
```

Now create a dictionary using the keys of d as the values and the values of d as the keys

```
>>> rev_d = dict((v,k) for k,v in d.items())
```

Your comparisons are now just regular dictionary lookups

```
>>> rev_d['b'] > rev_d['d']
True
```

Comment: The thing is values may be similar (there may be one or more of each value). And if i use this method, i will lose some information, as keys should be unique.

Comment: @Maks, if there are duplicates, there is no correct answer as you may have {3:'b', 5:'d', 7, 'b'} for example

Comment: Why not? B is the first in the {3:'b', 5:'d', 7:'b'}. I mean, yes, value "b" appears a few times, but it goes earlier than d in the beginning of the dictionary. As soon as the algorith sees that EITHER first appearing b goes in front of first appearing d OR first appearing d goes in front of first appearing b, algorith stops going through dictionary.

Comment: @Maks, remember that dictionaries have no order

Answer (score 0):

From your comment on [gnibbler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427981/determine-position-of-values-in-dictionary-python/4428037#4428037), it sounds like when there are multiple occurrences of a value, you only care about the earliest appearing one. In that case, the swapped (value, key)-dictionary suggested can still be used, but with minor modification to how you build it.

```
xs = {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'a'}
ys = {}
for k, v in xs.iteritems():
    if v not in ys or k < ys[v]:
        ys[v] = k
```

You could then define a function that tells you which of two values maps to a smaller index:

```
def earlier(index_map, a, b):
    """Returns `a` or `b` depending on which has a smaller value in `index_map`.

    Returns `None` if either `a` or `b` is not in `index_map`.

    """
    if a not in index_map or b not in index_map:
        return None

    if index_map[a] < index_map[b]:
        return a

    return b
```

Usage:

```
print earlier(ys, 'a', 'b')
```

There are some subtleties here whose resolution depends on your particular problem.

- What should happen if `a` or `b` is not in `index_map`? Right now we return `None`.
- What should happen if `index_map[a] == index_map[b]`? From your comments it sounds like this may not happen in your case, but you should consider it. Right now we return `b`.